# Does JavaScript provide a history of prior events that occurred?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was wondering if JavaScript records information about the prior events that occurred so that I could use the information to perform a specific course of action in the current event?

For example, I have an element that has an `OnBlur` event handler, but I would like to know the event that occurred prior to the `OnBlur` event that triggered the `OnBlur` event to occur, such as the user pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, arrow key, or mouse click that moved focus away from the element.

So does JavaScript provide any mechanism to facilitate access to the events history or can people throw ideas to me at good ways of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing native in JS that does this..

You could just listen for the events you are interested in and append them to an array or whatever datastructure is useful to you.  Then reference your own event database as needed.

So something like (JQuery assumed..)

```
var eventdb = [];
$(document).bind("click,blur,whatever", function(e) {
  eventdb.push(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such history maintained by any browser implementation: the history api I believe maintains URl traversal, but nothing tracks individual events. If you need one you will probably need to implement one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to any event on the object and maintain that event on the object for the next event handler.  Here is a jsfiddle that shows a binding to many events and storing the last event type on the object.  There is also a click event handler that makes a decision based on the last event saved on the object:  http://jsfiddle.net/xEjGA/